# Disprove: $\{\{ a,b\},b \}=\{\{ c,d\},d \}$ iff $a=c \ \ \text{and} \ b=d$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove/disprove:
>
> 1. For every four elements $a,b,c,d$ we have: $\{\{ a\},b \}=\{\{ c\},d \}$ iff $a=c \ \ \text{and} \ b=d$
> 2. For every four elements $a,b,c,d$ we have: $\{\{ a,b\},b \}=\{\{ c,d\},d \}$ iff $a=c \ \ \text{and} \ b=d$

I know the first is true and the second isn't. For 1. I can just say:

$\{\{ a\},b \}=\{\{ a\},b \}$ , $\{\{ c\},d \}=\{\{ c\},d \}$ and that's it (?) but for the second one I can't find a counter example.

Comment: You mean the first is false and the second is true, don't you?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen maybe whoever told me this was wrong...

Comment: So let's warm up with the first again: Isn't it possible under suitable circumstances that $\{a\}=d$ and $b=\{c\}$?

Comment: Dear @kuhaku, according to Wikipedia, a set is a collection of distinct objects, considered as an object in its own right. In particular, one can speak of a set of sets. For example, $\{\{a\}\}$ is a set with one element - $\{a\}$. Also, $\{a\}$ is a set with one element - $a$. However, these two sets are different since $a\neq \{a\}$. Does that make sense? It might be a little bit confusing, at first, but it is logically correct.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I meant those can't be right, just like $\emptyset \neq \{\emptyset \}$

Comment: For example, take $b$ and $d$ to be sets - $\{c\}$ and $\{a\}$, respectively.

Comment: @AmiteshDatta is that a counter example? the order of the elements in a set doesn't matter so it will still be true... Also isn't it against $b=d$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that when we write a set $S$ in enumerating form like $S=\{x,y\}$, there is no order on the elements imposed even though we write $x$ before $y$. Actually - and one sometimes has to be careful about this possibility! - it is not even necessarily the case that $x\ne y$. All we know from that notation is that for any $z$ we have
$$z\in S\iff z=x\lor z=y. $$

---

Now consider the first problem with these special elements: Let $a=\emptyset$,  $c=d=\{\emptyset\}$, $b=\{\{\emptyset\}\}$. Then $$\{\{a\},b\}=\{\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}=\{d,\{c\}\}=\{\{c\},d\}$$
and yet $a\ne c$ because $c$ is not empty (and also $b\ne d$). So this shows that there are counterexamples to the first problem.

---

Now assume that 
$$\tag1S:=\{\{a,b\},b\}=\{\{c,d\},d\} $$
and let us try to show that $a=b$ and $c=d$. (Of course the other direction - if $a=c$ and $b=d$ then $(1)$ - is trivial).
By the **Axiom of Foundation** there exists $x\in S$ such that $x\cap S=\emptyset$, i.e. the set
$$F:=\{\,x\in S\mid x\cap S=\emptyset\,\}$$
is nonempty. Since $b\in \{a,b\}\cap S$, we have $\{a,b\}\notin F$. We conclude that $F=\{b\}$. By the same argument, $F=\{d\}$.
But $\{b\}=\{d\}$ implies that $b=d$.
As a corollary, we see that $b\ne\{a,b\}$ because $b\in F$ and $\{a,b\}\notin F$. Therefore $S\setminus F=\{\{a,b\}\}=\{\{c,d\}\}$, hence
$T:=\{a,b\}=\{c,d\}$.
Now either $T\setminus F=\emptyset$, which implies $a\in F$ and hence $a=b$ (and likewise $c=d$); then $a=b=d=c$.
Or $T\setminus F$ is nonempty. Then necessarily $T\setminus F=\{a\}=\{c\}$ and hence again $a=c$. So in summary we indeed have $a=c$ and $b=d$.

Comment: Very detailed answer, thank you!